# Typical time for Waiting For Review?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I uploaded my first app to iTunes connect, on the 23rd it changed status to Waiting For Review. The box which shows the status of app reviews says 80-99% of apps in the last 5 days have been reviewed.

Does that include the Waiting For Review period, or only from the In Review period?

Basically how long should I wait before I wonder if it's disappeared down a black hole?
I have no problem with waiting weeks, just Im unsure what the percentage says actually mean.

EDIT: I also meant to ask if the the stats Apple give in the developer centre, include the Waiting For Review period?

Comment: This question is unanswerable. The review time depends directly on a closed process within Apple that no-one outside of Apple can talk about. The waiting times vary wildly from anything between an hour and a month or even longer. Just sit tight. It'll happen when it happens.

Comment: The question was more about the stats that apple provide (e.g. 99% of apps reviewed in the last five days) , but i guess I didn't word it very well. And it is answerable as no matter what the system is other people know how long it takes roughly. The answers provided below show that the question is answerable.

Comment: As according to the close reason I picked: "**This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors**; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, **a specific moment in time**, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet" - Emphasis mine. The review times *will* change, so any answers here are anecdotal and will not apply to everyone. They are not concrete answers, which is what Stack Overflow is built on and strives to achieve.

Comment: Funny how this was closed as too localised, but now has 2,500 views :)

Comment: that doesn't mean any answers will be helpful to anyone. Many, many people may ask the same question, seeking answers, but the nature of the review process means that no answer given by anyone will be definitive, and therefore has no place on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Uhuh, a answer voted up 8 times is completely useless. And not having a definitive answer is not being localised, it's being subjective.

Comment: I'm not going to argue the point further than this, but it wasn't just me, it required 4 other votes. However, part of the 'too localised' reason is: "extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet" - Everyone gets different review times. They vary wildly and are very different for different types of apps. Even an answer with 8 votes only links to a site with anecdotal data based on people tweeting their times. I could skew that by setting up a bot that tweets a review time of 1 hour. It's not going to help anyone in the long run.

Comment: Why discriminate questions whose answer is a distribution rather than a single value?

Comment: @Jasarien Well, this helped me out alot. The answer provided by septi, with 21 upvotes, was a great discovery. Maybe the question is narrow and to a specific moment in time, but the answer covers that.

Comment: I love how I just got the famous question badge (10k views) for a "question [that] is unlikely to help any future visitors"

Comment: @Jonathan. Haha yea nice one, and also look at the upvotes on my answer ; )

Comment: This question, and Jasarien's tortured logic, is a perfect example of why *Too Localized* is almost entirely a nonsense reason for closing a question.  +1 to Q and to A.

Comment: i searched for this 4 years after the fact, pretty relevant to anyone submitting an app

Answer (score 4):

Well, most of the apps i submitted into the App Store were submitted within 7 days - it does not make any difference if you submit new app or just an update. The latest update i submitted took 8 days to review, so maybe it's a bit 'crowded' at the moment.

Comment: I submitted an update on the 21st, it was approved the 29th.  And about a dozen past releases/updates have also been about 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, it could be between 1 day to 6 days. But you never know what might have prevented you app to go through..

Comment: Well it's not got into review yet, so they lily haven't even looked at it to find anything to prevent it going through, but thanks for your experience.