# iOS app release delay

Tags: ios, app-store

I have been looking around for some time now, but can't seem to find an answer.

My question is: when submitting an iOS app to apple, how long does the check take? Is it days or weeks before it is available in the app store (assuming it passes the tests)?

Timing is very crucial for this app, as we want it to be as good as possible, but as it is intended for a sports event taking 4 days, proper timing is essential to avoid release after the event has ended.

Hope somebody who has released one or more apps before could be helpful.

Thanks in advance. Thomas.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Typical time for Waiting For Review?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344526/typical-time-for-waiting-for-review)

Comment: Apple gives you this information here: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/index.html (you'll have to log in)

Comment: The time varies, normally, in my experience, from a bit less that 2 days to a little over 2 weeks, assuming no problems are found with the app.  When Apple is busy, the review times are at the longer end of the range.

Comment: My personal experience was 8 days with a simple app.  I've read it takes another 8 days for app updates.  So I'm submitting my first update soon, fingers crossed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the other answers, the time it takes Apple to review your app varies. In my experience it has been anywhere between a couple days and a couple weeks (too many variables to count), and this is of course assuming that your app isn't rejected for any reason.

However there is a work around for timing the release of your app just right. Make sure you submit it to Apple **WELL** in advance, and during the iTunes Connect new app creation process you will at some point be asked if you would like the app to automatically be released when it is approved, or if you would like to manually release it yourself. Go with the latter and you will at any point be able approve your app and it will be up on the App Store within a couple of hours.

If you have already selected automatic release and wish to change it, you can do this at any time in iTunes Connect by navigating to your app, selecting "Rights and Pricing" and adjusting your applications availability dates.

Answer (score 2):

When you submit an app, you can also provide an "availability date". So submit it well in advance, specifying your target release date, and it won't show up prior to that. See the [iTunes Connect Developer's Guide](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I would have it submitted a month or two in advance of the event.  This will allow you enough time to resolve any issues if the app is rejected the first time.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on what you're releasing.  Check through the App Store Guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html

If your app is at all questionable, it will take much longer.  If you go here you can see wha the average time it's taking for updating and releasing:

https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=03202012a

Currently it's about 5 days.  Most of my apps have taken a week.  One that was questionable took a month.  I would suggest submitting very early, at least a few weeks.  And then putting a release date that is later, so that it doesn't automatically release.

Answer (score 0):

The check varies - I've heard of apps taking anywhere from a day to several weeks (not very helpful, but the truth).

You will get an email saying your app is ready after it has passed the tests, but I will take several hours (up to 4ish) before it shows up in the App store. You may be able to find it by searching the name earlier, but it takes a few hours before it shows up in "recently added"

Answer (score 0):

5 to 6 days in my experience if everything is approved